# Matrix built with pairwise array values

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

Would you have an elegant solution to build a matrix, based on an array, given pairwise values x, y and z?

The input array:

```
A
A
B
B
C
```

The matrix to build (I have shown the index and header for comprehension but the final matrix is only the values):

```
    A   A   B   B   C
A   1   1   x   x   y
A   1   1   x   x   y
B   x   x   1   1   z
B   x   x   1   1   z
C   y   y   z   z   1
```

Comment: Can you explain the signifigance of the `x, y, and z`?  It looks like you want something like `a == a[:, None]` though.

Comment: `x, y and z` are dummy variables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea: create a dictionary with key the tuple (pair):

```
a = np.array(['A','A','B','B','C'])
d = {('A','A'):1,
     ('B','B'):1,
     ('C','C'):1,
     ('A','B'):x,
     ('A','C'):y,
     ('B','C'):z}
```

Create the matrix of tuples using `a[:, None]` and `a[None, :]`, I'm blocking here.
I should have something like this:

```
('A', 'A')  ('A', 'A')  ('A', 'B')  ('A', 'B')  ('A', 'C')
('A', 'A')  ('A', 'A')  ('A', 'B')  ('A', 'B')  ('A', 'C')
('B', 'A')  ('B', 'A')  ('B', 'B')  ('B', 'B')  ('B', 'C')
('B', 'A')  ('B', 'A')  ('B', 'B')  ('B', 'B')  ('B', 'C')
('C', 'A')  ('C', 'A')  ('C', 'B')  ('C', 'B')  ('C', 'C')
```

Any suggestion?

And then use `np.where` with the dictionary to replace the tuple with the given value.